# Continue when Its finish

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this Ajax Script:

```
if(ajax.readyState==4)
        {
        var respuesta=ajax.responseText;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
        $("#newaircraftdialog").dialog('close');

        $(document).ready(function(){
            refreshTable();
        });

        $("#loadingdialog").dialog('close');
        }
```

The function refreshTable:

```
function refreshTable(){
    $('#table').load('aircrafts_table.php');

}
```

The problem I have is that I want the `#loadingdialog` to close when previous function `refreshTable` completely finished. Now what it does is run the function, and then close the dialog, but the function needs time to refresh the table. So when you close the dialog function has not had time to update the table.

Comment: Why are you using `ajax.readyState` instead of a success callback?

Comment: why are you using document.ready() inside an ajax handler?

Comment: Probably you need a [callback](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/).

Comment: What is in your refreshTable function?

Comment: refreshTable is a funtion to Refrash a Table in the file.

Comment: I understand that it refreshes a table. But how? Is it doing another ajax request? Or..?

Comment: Ok, I put the code in the question!

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to call the dialog close() method once the refreshTable() method is finished. If the refreshTable() is calling an asynch method, then you need to call dialog's close method in the callback handler of that asynch method

@Edit: change your refreshtable() code into

```
function refreshTable(){
    $('#table').load('aircrafts_table.php', function(){
        //put that code to close that dialog box here
    });
}
```

Comment: For that you need to give details about your refreshTable() function

Comment: I put the function in the question post!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a callback parameter to the `refreshTable` function and then pass it whatever you wish to be run when it completes. For example:

```
function refreshTable(callback)
{

  /* ... (refresh table code) */

  if ('function' === typeof callback)
  {
    callback()
  }

}

/* ... (AJAX request) */

refreshTable(function ()
{
  $("#loadingdialog").dialog('close')
}
)
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console? For example, something along the lines of dialog not being a method of undefined, perhaps?

Comment: I dont know How Can I do that

Answer (score 0):

This way it should do like you want (see updated refresh table at the end of an answer):

```
if(ajax.readyState==4) {
        var respuesta=ajax.responseText;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
        $("#newaircraftdialog").dialog('close');
        refreshTable(function(){$("#loadingdialog").dialog('close');});
}
```

But I have no idea why you are mixing jQuery with pure JS (as it looks to me).

Suppose your code could be changed like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.ajax({url:ajax_url,
             method:'GET',
             dataType:'html',
             success:function(res){
                 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=res;
                 $("#newaircraftdialog").dialog('close');
                 refreshTable(function(){$("#loadingdialog").dialog('close');});

             });
     });
```

Please note that `$(document).ready(function() {})` is called only once, after document is completely loaded. And it is not called again after ajax is done.

```
function refreshTable(callback){
    $('#table').load('aircrafts_table.php', callback);

}
```

Comment: You might want to fix the `ajax.responseText` there.